# How do you get WordCount.java to compile on Cloudera 4?

Tags: java, hadoop, javac, cloudera, word-count

I'm trying to compile a simple WordCount.java map-reduce example on a linux (CentOS) installation of Cloudera 4. I keep hitting compiler errors when I reference any of the hadoop classes, but I can't figure out which jars of the hundreds under /usr/lib/hadoop I need to add to my classpath to get things to compile. Any help would be greatly appreciated! What I'd like most is a java file for word count (just in case the one I found is bad for some reason) along with the associated command to compile and run it.

I am trying to do this using just javac rather than Eclipse. My main issue either way is what exactly are the Hadoop libraries from the Cloudera 4 install which I need to include in order to get the classic WordCount example to compile. Basically, I need to put the Java MapReduce API classes (Mapper, Reducer, etc.) in my classpath.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a script that builds my hadoop classes.  Try:

```
#!/bin/bash

program=`echo $1 | awk -F "." '{print $1}'`

if [ ! -d "${program}_classes" ]
    then    mkdir ${program}_classes/;
fi

javac -classpath /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/h\
adoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar -d ${program}_classes/ $1

jar -cvf ${program}.jar -C ${program}_classes/ .;
```

You were probably missing the key jars:

```
 /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar
```

and

```
/usr/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the Cloudera CDH4 Virtual Machine then the following should get you running:

```
javac -classpath /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.0.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.0.0-cdh4.0.0.jar -d wordcount_classes WordCount.java
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can export environment:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default

export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar
```

and use the commands below:

```
$ bin/hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java

$ jar cf wc.jar WordCount*.class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse please do add Hadoop packages. you may get it from java2s or any similar sites. I couldn't say without know anything about what you did till now.